# Moved mysql database but no joy

Tags: mysql

it started out with a mysqldump not making a good file so importing to another server would bomb.  The last line of the sql file has this text in it:
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show events': Cannot proceed because system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start (1577)

I then searched on this site for some other options and found the option of jsut grabbing the folder that contains the database and moving it to the other server.  I tried that but then i get:
SQL show index from `archived_import_log` failed : Table 'cgaxf_800080.archived_import_log' doesn't exist

Now i am at a loss..any ideas?

Comment: Well if the table is damaged its damaged. Fix it first and then dump it. Moving a damaged database is not a solution

Comment: understood..what's strange is the application that database is running works fine on the origination server.  I am wondering if mysqldump is wrong here?

Comment: it was a mess.  It turns out mysql was manually installed outside of rpm.  The previous admin then upgraded mysql manually but didn't run mysql upgrade.  I had to crack the mysql admin password(it wasn't a very difficult one to figure out) so i could run the upgrade then I had to run the dangerious innodb recovery routine(luckily it didn't bork anything) and then i was able to get the dump to export properly.

Comment: FWIW, mysqldump was just telling you about an error thrown by the server. It's very unlikely for mysqldump to be "wrong" about something, since most of what it does is just run SQL queries and fail if they fail. The server's error log should also have been warning you about the issue with the system tables each time the server was restarted.